# This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97 Current browser version is 96.0.4664.45 with binary path error using Selenium and Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class instagrambot:

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

instagrambot()
```

Error :
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97
Current browser version is 96.0.4664.45 with binary path

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove ChromeDriver version 97 and install ChromeDriver version 96. This is what i did to fix the problem.

```
sudo apt remove chromium-chromedriver
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer. It would really help our readers if you could explain why and how your answer solves the OPs problems

Answer (score 0):

This mean that you have different versions of Chrome Browser and Chrome Driver.
Make sure you've installed the right version

**check browser v.**: chrome://settings/help

**check webdriver v.**: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Error : This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97 Current browser version is 96.0.4664.45 with binary path
```

...implies that the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chrome=96.0.4664.45*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v96.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 96

- But you are using *chromedriver=97.0*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=97.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/97.0.4692.36/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports Chrome version 97

So there is a clear mismatch between *chromedriver=97.0* and the *chrome=96.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v96.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=96.0.4664.45/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current _chrome=96.0.4664.45. (as per [chrome=96.0.4664.45 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/96.0.4664.45/notes.txt)).

Answer (score 0):

Type the following commands in the command prompt:

```
pip uninstall chromedriver_binary
pip install chromedriver-binary==96.0.4664.18.0
```

Answer (score 0):

go to chrome > help > About Google Chrome.  make sure chrome version is 97 and should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).